# Sub-Query in linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

What is the best way to write this query in linq?

```
SELECT *
  FROM product_master
  where product_id in (select product_id from product where buyer_user_id=12)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var _result =   from a in product_master
                where (product.Where(s => s.buyer_user_id == 12))
                        .Contains(a.product_ID)
                select a;
```

or

```
var _result =   (from a in product_master
                join b in product
                    on a.product_id equals b.product_id
                where b.buyer_user_id == 12
                select a).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

JW's answer is correct. Alternatively, given that the subquery is not correlated, you could express it separately:

```
var pids = product.Where(p => p.buyer_user_id == 12);
var r = product_master.Where(pm => pids.Contains(pm.product_id));
```